# Chrome goes to file when it's typed into the address bar?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome

I'm getting a strange issue on Google Chrome with my AppSpot app. Right now, I'm testing on localhost. Whenever I type in the address of the URL I want to go to, Chrome executes a GET request for that URL. This does not happpen in firefox. For example if I'm at the root:

`localhost:9080/`

Nothing happens, I waited for it to "automatically" do something, but as expected, it just sat there. However, when I started to type in :

`localhost:9080/point?special=123` (which is the URL that I want to go), Chrome sends a GET request to it before I hit enter. In the dev console, there is no network packet, but in my Log Console I get this:

```
INFO     2014-01-18 17:04:39,684 module.py:612] default: "GET /point?special=123 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

This is really strange, is it some kind of thing that Chrome does to speed up requests?

Thanks!

EDIT: This "prerendering" is also affecting my database, because it writes onto the database by itself..

Comment: Yes, it goes and gets the page it thinks you are going to go to before you complete the web address.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the setting

> Predict network actions to improve page load performance

In Chrome's advanced settings to disable this.

Comment: Thank you, but what about others using my program? It would be a pain to have them manually disable this to use my app. EDIT: Is there some sort of Javascript "stopper" that'll disable this behavior? Or even in Python?

Comment: There are similar apps you can use that do this, and lots of similar schemes. I think you are probably better off making your app cope with these pre-caching behaviours then any other option.

Comment: Okay thanks. And just to clarify, when Chrome "pre-renders" a page, does it load it again when the user *actually* goes to it?

Comment: Thanks! I just tested it out, I think it's working fine.